# How to convert hex string to dec string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hex

I have a long hex string like a `f713637d185e61e9bcea04487a86a501981096941416412bd9809f743e2d79790574f678fc8a01c684778de872da6cb4` and I need to convert it to long dec string like a `38028436380513374353265995855941660177945156565669892070998148016602400854965335529242835215373689843417022113410228`. Input string may be longer. How to implement it using Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use BigInteger to parse it:

```
val decimalString = BigInteger(hexString, 16).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.Long.parseLong("ED05265A", 16)
```

This is a java method, but because of the interoperability, you should be able to use it just fine.

Comment: What about Long size? Input string may be longer.

Comment: well if your number is bigger than 9223372036854775807 then it probably wouldn't work, because that's the largest value that can be stored in a kotlin long

Comment: Less awkward to use `"ED05265A".toLong(16)`.